# FTP connection issue in UNIX

Tags: ftp, tcp, cisco

So cisco intrusion prevention system(IPS) runs on UNIX platform.
we have been facing this FTP issue where the three way handshake gets completed, the ftp sends a FTP 220 request to the IPS. But the IPS doesn't respond,eventually after few minutes the FTP timesout.
in terms of UNIX how can i troubleshoot this??

Comment: switch between active / passive transfer mode.